# Does something like a VB "Variant" implementation exist which uses C#'s dynamic dispatch?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, variant

I realize that it goes against the strongly typed nature of C#, but I find that when working with dynamic objects in the language, some of the more useful features typically found in JavaScript or PowerShell are simply not practical.

For example, the following C# code will fail at runtime and it's obvious why.

```
dynamic x = 1.0;
int y = x;
```

But that makes the dynamic features of C# pretty limited when dealing with loosely typed data such as that produced by JSON payloads or CSV where subtle variations in the representation can result in very different behavior at runtime.

What I'm looking for is something that will behave much like the VBA / VBScript era `Variant` type. I imagine it's possible to derive such a type from `DynamicObject` that would wrap primitive values like `Int32`, `String`, etc and perform the appropriate casts at runtime. [I've done something similar](https://gist.github.com/2789805) with "null" values in dynamic contexts.

But is there anything like this already established? I've looked around GitHub or Codeplex to no avail but it's kind of a hard thing to search for. Before I get started on what I imagine is going to be quite a complicated class, I want to make sure I'm not wasting my time.

#### About the practicality of all of this

I should note that I resisted the concept of dynamic dispatch in C# for a long time because it  was not intended to be a dynamic language. Quite honestly, I wish it wasn't added to the language at all, or at least restricted to COM interop scenarios.

But having said that, I am always curious about ways to "hack" language features in such a way to make them do things that they were never intended to do. Sometimes something useful comes out of it. For example, there have been plenty of examples of people using the `IDisposable` interface and `using` statement to do things that have nothing to do with releasing resources.

I doubt I would use this in production applications or anything that needed to be handed off to another developer.

Comment: Honestly I'd rather write the code to map the Json/Csv into strong typed data model classes the try to muddle through with something like this.

Comment: @asawyer - I generally agree. This is more of an experiment in "hacking" dynamic to make it behave in interesting ways. I probably would not want to do this in production code that I want to be around for a while.

Comment: You can do this if you want; write a container type that implements the interface

Comment: Sorry I am on a phone and the edit/delete UI doesn't work on it, so I can't get rid of that bad comment!  I meant inherit from dynamicobject, and then you can do all the crazy stuff you want.  As long as you're happy with a wrapping type. Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx

Comment: @AndrasZoltan - Yep that's exactly what I intend on doing. I was just unsure if there was anything either in the framework or a well established library like Json.net that already tackled it, then I wouldn't bother. But at least I am more confident that I explained myself correctly in my post because that's exactly what I was getting at.

Answer (score 4):

The visual basic languages hide a lot of the glue, that just isn't the C# way.  The Variant type has a raft of conversion functions, they are invoked automatically by the vb runtime.  .NET has automatic conversion functions too, you just have to use them explicitly:

```
dynamic x = 1.0;
int y = Convert.Int32(x);
```

With the C# justification for having to write code like that because it is not a language that hides cost.

Comment: I’m not so sure about the “hides cost” argument (autoboxing …), I’d rather say the reason here is that C# doesn’t hide unverifiable assertions. Putting a `dynamic` into an integer makes a pretty strong claim about he runtime behaviour of the program, and C# doesn’t want to pretend that it can vouch for this.