# VB copyoBjects Late Binding

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010, autocad, late-binding

I have the following code which I am trying in VB. NET giving **Invalid Object Array** when I try to copy objects. Where am I doing wrong?

```
Option Strict Off

'Imports Autodesk
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Data
'Imports Autodesk.AutoCAD
'Imports Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop.Common
'Imports Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop

Public Class Form1

    Private acadApp As Object 'AcadApplication
    Private m_oActiveDoc As Object 'AcadDocument

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim oSourceFile As Object = Nothing 'AcadDocument

        Try
            acadApp = GetObject(, "AutoCAD.Application.16")
            m_oActiveDoc = acadApp.ActiveDocument

            Dim oTempDoc As Object 'Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop.AcadDocument
            For Each oTempDoc In acadApp.Documents

                If UCase("c:\d1.dwg") = UCase(oTempDoc.Path & "\" & oTempDoc.Name) Then
                    oSourceFile = oTempDoc
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next

            If oSourceFile IsNot Nothing Then

                Dim objCollection(0) As Object 'AcadBlock ' Object!!!!!!!!!!!

                objCollection(0) = Nothing

                Try
                    objCollection(0) = oSourceFile.Blocks.Item("b1")

                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.Message)

                End Try

                If objCollection(0) IsNot Nothing Then

                    oSourceFile.CopyObjects(objCollection, m_oActiveDoc.Blocks) 'Invalid object array exception when objCollection is declared as Object.
                End If
            End If


        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)

        End Try
    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: That's because you're trying to access a version of autocad that doesn't have a .NET API. I believe you can go back as far as 2007.

Comment: I am using AutoCad2009. Second I am able to do every other thing in early Binding. How version would be an issue in late binding. Can you please explain? I am using InterOp, not .NET API

Comment: `Autocad.Application.16` is a reference to autocad 2004 you need `Autocad.Application.17` I'm not sure if you need the subversion in that line of code. If so it's `Autocad.Application.17.2` the Interop libraries are also part of the .NET API. Are you trying to use vba? Is that what late/early binding is? I've never used it.

Comment: That was by mistake. Yes I am using *Autocad.Application.17* I am using VB.NET and I need to make copyObject in late Binding. I can go for C# if it works. I am getting same error on it too

Comment: Try declaring `oTempDoc` as `Dim oTempDoc As Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop.AcadDocument`

Comment: @rwisch45 will it not  become a early binding?

Comment: Yes, but is there a problem with that? You could also change each of your generic Objects to be strongly typed Auto Cad objects - that would do away with letting the compiler infer their type as it seems to be unneccessary here. EXCEPT for the initial declaration of `acadApp as Object` - once you get past this line `acadApp = GetObject(, "AutoCAD.Application.16")` then you are working with `acadApp` as an `AutoCad.Application.16` and not as a plain object anymore

Comment: @rwisch45 are you saying that once calling main application Object in late binding I don't need to convert other Objects in late Binding anymore and I can call copyObjects with variable of type ACadDocument?

Comment: I haven't worked with any AutoCad libraries before. That being said, it looks like in your case that the only thing that should be initially declared as an Object is `acadApp`.

Comment: My question was: if Parent Object is assigned a type via Late binding then will all child methods need to use *REFLECTION* to call every other member methods in late binding or I can assign a type with them?

Comment: Use .NET 4.0 with the Dynamic keyword and you won't need to use reflection to have access to late-bound objects at runtime.

Comment: @Locke can you please explain how and where I can use Dynamic keyword?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AutoCad: Getting 'Invalid object array exception' in Late Binding while copying Objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18554773/autocad-getting-invalid-object-array-exception-in-late-binding-while-copying)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does something like a VB "Variant" implementation exist which uses C#'s dynamic dispatch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760071/does-something-like-a-vb-variant-implementation-exist-which-uses-cs-dynamic)